# Implementing the function interrupt with if statements

Tags: arduino, interrupt

I want to implement the function interrupt () but I don't know exactly how..In this case there is 2 for loops which can be seen in the code:I want whenever one of the 2 buttons is pressed the process inside the loop to be interrupted immediately:

```cpp
void loop() {
    int brightButton = digitalRead(K1);
    int ldrStatus = analogRead(ldrPin);

    if (brightButton == LOW && ldrStatus >= 200)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            digitalWrite(greenLed, HIGH);
            tone(buzzer,400);
            delay(500);
            noTone(buzzer);
            delay(500);
        }
    }
    else {
        digitalWrite(greenLed, LOW);
    }

    int tempButton = digitalRead(K2);
    int valNTC = analogRead(NTC);

    if (tempButton == LOW && valNTC > 512)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <10; i++)
        {
            digitalWrite(redLed, HIGH);
            tone(buzzer,450);
            delay(300);
            noTone(buzzer);
            delay(1000);
        }
    }
    else {
        digitalWrite(redLed, LOW);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried 3 different websearch engines and every single one provided the respective Arduino manual as first hit for "Arduino interrupt"... please read [ask]. a minimum of own research is expected

Answer (score 1):

Example code from the Arduino manual:

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/

```
const byte ledPin = 13;
const byte interruptPin = 2;
volatile byte state = LOW;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), blink, CHANGE);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(ledPin, state);
}

void blink() {
  state = !state;
}
```

Note that this will interrupt the for loop and return to it once the interrupt service routine is finished.
If you want to abort the for loop check the pin state in every loop cycle and break if you want to leave the for loop or return if you want to leave loop().
Of course this is not "immediately".